# Registering COM class to run as a service

Tags: winapi, com, registry, atl, dcom

I'm developing a DCOM application that should run as a service.
I've managed to make this app work as a standalone app (the client requests the component, and OS starts the standalone app) - to do it, I'm executing
MyApp.exe /regserver
But after I run
MyApp.exe /service
the client can't reach the app - neither when the service is not running, nor when it is running.
The client is not developed by me (actually, that's Excel RTD function), so I can't check at what step the problem is happening.
So, how should I register a class/app so that it runs as a service?
Developed in VS2013, created ATL project "service exe".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COM registration for service ATL project is very much similar to its application mode: the same registry keys for COM classes with the only difference that the server is hosted by service. More important for you however is that clients access service COM objects across session boundary, and with different credentials. YourApp.exe is running as service logged on as Local System (unless you changed it manually or tweaked COM registration code), whereas clients are logged on as users.

Making it a service, make sure to review [Launch and Activation Permissions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771916.aspx) for your COM objects. For troubleshooting, you might also want to change user account for your service to match user running the client application (to rule out problems related to permissions and different user accounts).

Comment: Registration is not *exactly* the same.  When hosted as a service, the COM class registration needs an [`AppID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682359.aspx) with a [`LocalService`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693774.aspx) value to specify the service name, so COM can start the service it is not already running.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: yes, this is included in "very much similar". Same keys, minor service related differences. The point is that "/service" covers this entirely (in particular: one does not have to do `LocalService` from code - ATL does it out of the box), and the typical problems are related to permissions, not registration itself.

Comment: That was my impression, too. What I did is:
- created HKCR/CLSID/{ProgID of class} with key CLSID having correct CLSID
- created HKCR/CLSID/{CLSID of class} with value AppID of the app
- created HKCR/AppID/{AppID of app} with value LocalService = service name
- Using dcomcnfg, allowed everything to "Everyone"
I have debug output on server start and on class start. But the log is empty.
The good thing is - HKCR/CLSID/{CLSID} has key "LocalServer32", but there's no attempt to run as a serer, so I think it finds the LocalService in HKCR/AppID/{AppID of my app}, but for some reason fails to run.

Comment: N.B.: If I run the service manually from computer management - it runs fine, but even in this case the COM client (specifically, Excel RTD) can't reach my app.

Comment: Having the client you cannot debug is a problem, but for starters you can make a simple command line app with `CoInitialize` + `CoCreateInstance` and see if it can create your service hosted COM object.